# sharepoint and ssrs report error with xml datasource

Tags: reporting-services

I have a sharepoint 2013 farm with sql server 2012 installed in sharepoint integrated mode. reporting service is running on web front end server. I create reports that contains data sources from sql server tables and sharepoint lists and then put them in web page via report viewer webpart and they work properly.

Now I need to filter results from sharepoint list according to report parameter value so I try to connect to sharepoint lists with xml type datasource. so I create datasource with this settings:

```
Data Source Type: XML
Connection String: http://mysiteurl.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
Dredentials: Stored credential > Use as Windows credentials
```

and create a dataset and set to use this data source. It can connect to sharepoint list because return list’s fields but when I run the report get the following error:

```
Query execution failed for dataset 'a'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.Unauthorized: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (rsXmlDataProviderError)
```

Any idea? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a double hop problem.  See here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a8ce234f-dffc-46ed-8b88-5de4f8626ac1/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized-rsxmldataprovidererror?forum=sqlreportingservices